# Swift enum: perform code on value change?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

Swift enums have various wonders, such as initialization, and you can write a mutating function, and more.

But I'm wondering, can you simply have it **run some code, when the value changes**??

So, of course using a property + enum, you can do just that ... which is fantastic.

**(Note, vadian below gives an excellent full example of doing just that.)**

So my question is simply, does Swift enum have a feature that lets you **run code whenever the value changes**?

Or, in a word, do you have to use a property/mutation combo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But I'm wondering if literally within enum in Swift there is a concept to "run code when the value changes".

No. An enum is a value type. When the value changes, the old value is completely destroyed and replaced with a new one. If you want mutable state, you should use a class or mutable struct, and `didSet` with a property.

Comment: Say Aaron.  I appreciate that the answer is "no", and thanks for that.  However, help me understand what you mean *"enum is a value type. When the value changes, the old value is completely destroyed and replaced with a new one"*...  that happens with any property (which could indeed be an enum) including the ordinary case of a value type. And of course it's perfectly normal to run some code, when, a value type happens to change.  So I'm not really sure if I follow what you mean on the "reasoning" there. In all events, thanks!

Comment: Think of it like an `Int`. If `var x = 3`, you would not expect the `Int`, `3`, to be able to react when you later say `x = 4`. The 3 is simply destroyed and replaced by the 4. From the perspective of `Int`, nothing is changing. Similarly, when you change the enum, `Gate` may be destroyed and replaced by `Laps`.

Comment: I guess that makes good sense.  If you make the Int a property - that's a whole other thing.  It's not then the Int "3" that has to Know.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an instance variable / property of type `RaceState` and change the values in the observer `didSet`

```
enum RaceState { case Gate, Laps, Pits }

class Foo {

  var raceState : RaceState {
    didSet {
      if oldValue != raceState {
        switchState(raceState)
      }
    }
  }

  init(state : RaceState) {
    self.raceState = state
    switchState(state)
  }

  func switchState(state : RaceState)
  {
    switch state {
    case .Gate:
      engine.sound = false
      lights.hidden = true
      score.hidden = true
      start.hidden = false
    case .Laps:
      engine.sound = true
      lights.hidden = true
      score.hidden = false
      start.hidden = false
    case .Pits:
      engine.sound = true
      lights.hidden = false
      score.hidden = true
      start.hidden = false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Right on. Thanks for giving a full and correct example of that. As I say in the question *"of course using a property + enum, you can do just that ... which is fantastic."*.  I was wondering whether enum has syntax for running code when the value changes: it looks like the answer is simply "No"!

Comment: Indeed, the answer is: No

Comment: For that handy one-word answer, I say a handy "thanks" !  :-)

Comment: Thanks again for the superb answer and code reference. This will be hugely useful to many. (I ticked Aaron's since it was first and contains a great explanation; it's ridiculous you can't send 'reward points" on SO, thanks again.)